# How can i convert duration into hours only instead of days and hours using python 3 in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter

Here I am attaching the code screenshots.

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZsce.png)

```
from datetime import datetime
filmpermits['StartDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(filmpermits.StartDateTime) 
filmpermits['EndDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(filmpermits.EndDateTime)

filmpermits.head()  
# filmpermits.dtypes
```

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izFkT.png)

```
duration = filmpermits.EndDateTime - filmpermits.StartDateTime
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Screenshots of code are hard to work with. Can you edit your post and paste in your actual code instead of a screenshot? This will help people copy it when testing and attempting to solve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate this straight away when you calculate the duration. You just need to specify the type in hours:

```
duration = (filmpermits.EndDateTime - filmpermits.StartDateTime).astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. your suggestion worked for me mostly. But, I think it rounds up the numbers, right? it is giving in "int" type only.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i convert duration into hours only instead of days and hours …

Your `duration` is a *Series* of [pandas.Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html), which has a method `total_seconds()` from which we can compute the number of hours:

```
hours = duration.dt.total_seconds()/60/60
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but it is not working for me. Can we chat over this so that I can describe more in detail? Here there is no way to chat so your email id or something?

Comment: I overlooked that you have a Series of Timedeltas; I adjusted the answer.